# Cheeger inequality for the maximal eigenvalue

Tags: spectral-graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an undirected graph and let $L = I - D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$ be its normalized Laplacian matrix.  The Cheeger inequality asserts that:
$$\frac{\Phi_G^2}{2} \leq \lambda_2 \leq 2 \Phi_G$$
where $\lambda_2$ is the second smallest eigenvalue of $L$ (the smallest is necessarily $0$) and $\Phi_G$ is the optimal isoperimetric ratio of a set of vertices:
$$\Phi_G = \min_{vol(S) \leq vol(G)/2} \frac{|\partial S|}{vol(S)}$$
This inequality can be regarded as a quantitative counterpart of the more elementary observation that $\lambda_2 = 0$ if and only if $G$ is disconnected.

Another elementary observation is that $\lambda_{max} = 2$ if and only if $G$ is bipartite.  My question is:

> Is there a "Cheeger inequality" for $\lambda_{max}$?

If we define $\Psi_G = \max_S \frac{2 |\partial S|}{vol(G)}$ then one can prove that
$$\lambda_{max} \geq 2 \Psi_G$$
by adapting the argument used to prove $\lambda_2 \leq 2 \Phi_G$.  This is promising, because $|\partial S|$ is a good measure of how far a graph is from being bipartite; in particular, $\Psi_G = 1$ if and only if $G$ is bipartite.  Of course, one expects that finding an upper bound for $\lambda_{max}$ should be the hard part, just as the lower bound for $\lambda_2$ is the hard part of the classical Cheeger inequality.

The typical proof of the classical Cheeger inequality uses a certain variational interpretation of $\lambda_2$ and there is a similar interpretation of $\lambda_{max}$.  However, it is not clear (to me) how to adapt the proof of the Cheeger inequality to $\lambda_{max}$.  But computer experiments suggest that the strategy of the proof of the classical Cheeger inequality should work for $\lambda_{max}$: a sweep over an eigenvector for $\lambda_{max}$ produces a cut with large $\Psi_G$ just as a sweep over an eigenvector for $\lambda_2$ produces a cut with small $\Phi_G$.  So I feel there must be something there, and it would kind of surprise me if nobody has worked this out (though I was not able to find anything in the standard spectral graph theory references).

Answer (score 2):

You should see information on the Dual Cheeger constant. See for example:

Bauer-Hua-Jost, The dual Cheeger constant and spectra of infinite graphs

http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3410

and

Liu, Multi-way dual Cheeger constants and spectral bounds of graphs

http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3147